# javaで、ここから更に＂00:00にfalseと表示する＂を追加したいのですがどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: java

```
public class MemoTest {
 static Random random = new Random();
 static String verses[] = {
  "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"
 };
 static Memo[] memos;
 /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  initialize();
 }
 private static void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
  memos = new Memo[10];
  memos[0] = new Memo(new Time(7, 0), "Get up !");
  memos[1] = new Memo(new Time(8, 30), "Give me a verse", (Memo alarm) -> {
    System.out.println("Today's verse: " + verses[random.nextInt(verses.length)]);
  });
  memos[2] = new Memo(new Time(12, 10), "Lunch time ...");
  memos[3] = new Memo(new Time(17, 10), "Call my mother", new Notify() {
   @Override
   public void todo(Memo alarm) {
    // Send a message to mother that I am going home
   }
  });
  memos[4] = new Memo(new Time(17, 30), "Go home ~");
  memos[5] = new Memo(new Time(11, 10), "Go to sleep :)");
  memoService();
 }
 /**
  * Check each alarm whether it is time up. If yes, notify me and set the
  * notified flag to true
  *
  * @param now
  */
 private static void checkForReset(Date now) {
 }
 private static void memoService() throws InterruptedException {
  while (true) {
   Date now = new Date();
   checkForReset(now);
   for (Memo memo : memos) {
    if (memo != null) {
     if (!memo.notified && memo.time.timeup(now)) {
      memo.notified = true;
      memo.notify.todo(memo);
     }
    }
   }
   Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: このサイトについてはmetaに質問してください　https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: 既にポジティブな回答が付いているので、通常の手順では質問を削除することはできません。詳しくは次のヘルプを参照してください。 - 参考: [質問を取り消したいですが削除しても良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memos[5] = new Memo(new Time(11, 10), "Go to sleep :)");
```

の後ろに

```
memos[6] = new Memo(new Time(0, 0), "false");
```

でしょうか。